# Is it ok to store salesforce leads after user gives OAuth access

Tags: rest-api, permissions

In my web application, I am asking user to gives permission for reading salesforce data. The scopes requested are following -

```
api id refresh_token
```

With this scope, salesforce permission prompt looks like this -

[image]

With this permission, am I allowed to store leads in my database. Do I have to explicitly ask user to give 'store' permissions as well?

If so, relevant links will be helpful.